How to open custom keyboard instead of default virtual keyboard when click on EditText in Android Studio?
My following code has prevented opening the default virtual keyboard, but it clears text cursor inside EditText too.
Have any way to do both of them at the same time?
mEdtSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Show your custom keyboard here
        mActivity.showKeyboard(RoomListFragment.this);
    }
});

